# How do I import a large XML dump into a MediaWiki hosted by x10hosting?

Tags: xml, mediawiki, web-hosting, dump

I would like to import a large XML dump (17.9 MB) to my x10hosting MediaWiki 1.25.1, but as you may or may not know x10hosting does not grant users (or at least not free users like me) shell access hence I cannot use the `importDump.php` script in the `maintenance/` directory.

Using the Special:Import page does not work with such large dumps as it takes too long and the maximum import time is reached before the whole dump can be imported. Hence I am rather desperate for any ideas that others may have for how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Raise execution time limits, split up the dump into smaller chunks or import in the database directly (the last one is probably a bad idea unless you know what you are doing, though). There are also some extensions to allow running maintenance scripts from the web: [Maintenance](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Maintenance) and [MaintenanceShell](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MaintenanceShell) (I haven't used either).

Comment: How do I raise the execution time limits?

Comment: `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in PHP, plus whatever your webserver uses.